# Why all network traffic goes through Hyper-V switch?

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v, windows-11

I installed Hyper-V and created a VM, added external virtual switch.

I just realised that now the whole host machine traffic goes through it too. Why? Whats the latency of this unwanted "magic"? Can it be avoided?

*As you on the picture the "real" connection should be the "Ethernet 2" but everything goes into "vEthernet (external..)"*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why?

If you make the switch "external", i.e. attached to a physical network interface, then some part of the OS needs to decide which Ethernet frames are meant for the host OS and which ones for the virtual switch. It makes this decision by MAC address (frames sent to original host MAC need to be delivered to host OS, all others to the switch).

Since this filtering happens to be exactly what the vSwitch does *anyway* (forwarding based on destination MAC is literally the purpose of a switch), the Hyper-V developers have apparently decided to just *use* the vSwitch for that.

> Can it be avoided?

No, except by installing a second physical Ethernet port.

As mentioned, if the port is to be shared between the host OS and a vSwitch, then *something* has to divide traffic between the two – if it's not the vSwitch's FDB itself, then it would have to be a second tier of filtering that does the same thing as the first one.

Although this (hypothetical) second filtering tier could possibly make its decision faster and slightly reduce latency for host OS traffic because it only does a single comparison, it would result in the opposite for *guest* traffic (the latency of both tiers would add up – first the host/not-host MAC check, then the vSwitch FDB), and that would be equally undesirable for Hyper-V hosts.

If you had two physical Ethernet ports on the machine, then you could dedicate one of them for the host and the other for your vSwitch, so your host OS would be unaffected (though the

Comment: good news everyone :) I have 2 lan ports. now i just hope the Hyper-V allows to remove external switch from the port I want and move it to another..

Answer (score 1):

A Hyper-V external switch is a bridged network connection (generic language) that uses the router that the Host connects to via the Host Network adapter.

So you would then expect all traffic to go through this host adapter.

In fact, a guest NAT connection also goes through the Host network connection.

By virtue of this, the network traffic through the host NIC cannot be prevented.

I am assuming a Workstation (or Laptop) with 1 NIC.